I got the below Exception for working with spring boot chat application
I try to change the below code for the changes
@Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
    registry.enableSimpleBroker("/topic","/queue");
    registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    registry.setUserDestinationPrefix("/user");
}

@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/ws").withSockJS();
}

But I got this error:
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected destination pattern "/user/{userId}/**"
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:111) ~[spring-core-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.messaging.simp.user.DefaultUserDestinationResolver.parseMessage(DefaultUserDestinationResolver.java:188) ~[spring-messaging-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.messaging.simp.user.DefaultUserDestinationResolver.parse(DefaultUserDestinationResolver.java:158) ~[spring-messaging-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.messaging.simp.user.DefaultUserDestinationResolver.resolveDestination(DefaultUserDestinationResolver.java:128) ~[spring-messaging-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.messaging.simp.user.UserDestinationMessageHandler.handleMessage(UserDestinationMessageHandler.java:217) ~[spring-messaging-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.messaging.support.ExecutorSubscribableChannel$SendTask.run(ExecutorSubscribableChannel.java:152) ~[spring-messaging-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    ... 20 common frames omitted

How can I fix it?

I had the same problem as you. I just read "WebSocket," so maybe my solution will only work for me:
You should send the destination pattern (In this case, it is '/user/{userId}/**'). You can use SimpMessagingTemplate, For example:
 @Controller
 @RequiredArgsConstructor
 public class UserController {
 
     private final SimpMessagingTemplate messagingTemplate;
 
     @MessageMapping("/user.addUser")
     public UserEntity add(@Payload UserEntity user) {
 
         UserEntity saved = service.save(user);
         messagingTemplate.convertAndSend(
                 "/user/" + saved.getId() + "/**",
                 saved
         );
         return saved;
     }
 }

